# returned iterator has the wrong value

Tags: c++, std

I'm just trying to create wrapper functions around some std algorithm functions that I use frequently like `find` and `find_if` and others.

But for some reason when I use my wrapper function the returned iterator has the wrong value.

This code fails:

```
template<typename Container, typename ElementType>
typename Container::const_iterator
find(Container c, const ElementType& e)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), e);
}

template <typename T, typename Container>
bool
within_container(const T& element, const Container& v)
{
    return find(v, element) != v.end();
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int key = 10;
    bool res  = within_container(key, v);
    assert(res == false);
}
```

while this code runs fine:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
bool
within_container(const T& element, const Container& v)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), element) != v.end();
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int key = 10;
    bool res  = within_container(key, v);
    assert(res == false);
}
```

What am I missing?

I'm compiling with g++7.3 on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `Container c` as a function parameter makes a copy of the vector, and so iterators are invalidated as soon as the function returns

Comment: You sir, are a master. Thanks for the catch. Please post it as an answer so that I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `find` function template takes `c` by value and returns iterators to an object that is destroyed when the function returns, leading to undefined behaviour in the caller.

It could be fixed by using `Container&& c` (a forwarding reference) as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by passing a `const Container&` but your answer definitely works.